Embed digital signature into mp4 file
I am looking for away to embed a digital signature into mp4. I believe the signature can be prepared with OpenSSL, using a private key.
From what I read, the signature can be added to the mp4 as meta data (ffmpeg, etc.) However, this will change the mp4 file, and it will not be possible the verify the signature with OpenSSL.
Is there a process/standard to sign/verify the mp4 content part ?

Not clear... How is it a problem that adding new data (the signature) will change the MP4 file? Naturally, It will change (in size & content) because it now has some extra bytes. If the file bytes cannot be changed (eg: for "validity" checks etc) then just keep a separate note somewhere that relates to which video file goes with which certificate file (could be by MP4 filename or a "title" if you put such entry in the metadata). The database could be as simple as a text or JSON file listing the filename and showing the related signature's text (base64???). Extract text for OpenSSL checks.

Sorry for unclear question. I would like to sign only the “content” parts of the mp4, and ignore meta data that is included. Next I want to embed the signature into the mp4 file. Working with existing system p, which can not be modified to pick signatures from a “side” file. Hope it’s clearer.

It's getting clearer... (1) To sign only the “content” parts (excluding the metadata) means that you have to separate the two parts. In an MP4 the two sections have String names "moov" for metadata and then "mdat" for the content part as media data. You can write code to load a file into an Array then look for the letters (in hex digits). I'll advise, if you want to extract those bytes and you know how to get them (extracts) signed in some way. (2) Not clear what your "existing system" expects. Is it an MP4 file? Find out where it expects the signature to be located then let me know.

Existing system works only with mp4
